# OAuth2 Implementation

Tags: python, oauth, jwt

I am trying to implement an OAuth2 service. I am not planning to use it anytime soon (like will write unit tests). This is my fun project I do to practice. I have used the [python_jwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python_jwt) library to create and validate signatures.

#### OAuth Request handler

```
"""
 Copyright (C) 2016 Maruf Maniruzzaman
 Website: https://github.com/kuasha/cosmos
 Author: Maruf Maniruzzaman
 License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License

 This service handler follows the style found in Azure (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx)
 Also for more information look at The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)
"""

import ast
import base64
import json

import datetime
import uuid

import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
import logging

from cosmos.rbac.object import COSMOS_USERS_OBJECT_NAME
from cosmos.auth.oauth2 import get_token
from cosmos.rbac.object import SYSTEM_USER

try:
    import urlparse  # py2
    from urllib import urlencode
    import urllib as urllib_parse
except ImportError:
    import urllib.parse as urlparse  # py3
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    import urllib.parse as urllib_parse

from cosmos.service.requesthandler import RequestHandler

OAUTH2_REQUESTS_OBJECT_NAME = "cosmos.auth.oauth2.requests"
OAUTH2_TOKENS_OBJECT_NAME = "cosmos.auth.oauth2.tokens"
OAUTH2_CODE_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME = "cosmos.auth.oauth2.codestatus"
OAUTH2_MAX_CODE_RESPONSE_LENGTH = 200

class OAuth2RequestException(Exception):
    pass

#TODO: security check for entire class

class OAuth2ServiceHandler(RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, tenant_id, function):
        try:
            req_id = None
            auth_request = None
            serve_request = self.get_argument("serve_request", None)
            if not (serve_request):
                auth_request = self._collect_auth_request_parameters(tenant_id, function)

                req_id = yield self.insert_auth_request(auth_request)

                if not req_id:
                    logging.critical("Could not save OAuth2 request to database.")
                    raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Server error")

                logging.debug("Request saved in db {0}".format(str(req_id)))
            else:
                req_id = self.get_argument("serve_request")
                auth_request = yield self.load_auth_request(req_id)
                if not auth_request:
                    self.write("Could not find auth request. Correlation id {}".format(req_id))
                    self.finish()
                    return

            user = self.get_current_user()

            if not user:
                url = self.request.uri
                parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
                query = {"serve_request": str(req_id)}
                parts[4] = urlencode(query)

                redirect_url = urlparse.urlunparse(parts)

                self.initiate_login(redirect_url)

            if function == "authorize":
                yield self._do_authorize(user, auth_request)
                return
            elif function == "token":
                yield self._do_token(user, auth_request)
                return
            else:
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404, "Not found")
        except OAuth2RequestException as re:
            self.clear()
            self.set_status(400)
            self.finish("<html><body>400 Bad Request<br/>{}</body></html>".format(str(re)))

    @gen.coroutine
    def _do_authorize(self, user, params):
        response_type = params.get("response_type", None)
        if not "code" == response_type:
            raise OAuth2RequestException("Response type must be code")

        client_id = params.get("client_id", None)
        redirect_uri = params.get("redirect_uri", None)
        state = params.get("state", None)
        resource = params.get("resource", None)

        oauth2_public_key_handler = self.settings.get("oauth2_public_key_handler")

        code_attributes = ["user_id", "client_id", "resource", "iat", "code_status_id"]

        response = {}
        response.update({"user_id": user["_id"]})
        response["client_id"] = client_id
        response["resource"] = resource
        response["iat"] = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())

        code_status_id = yield self.insert_code_status(response)
        if not code_status_id:
            logging.critical("Could not save [OAuth2 Code] to database.")
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Server error")

        response["code_status_id"] = str(code_status_id)

        code_response = { k: response.get(k) for k in code_attributes }

        str_response = json.dumps(code_response)
        bytes_resp = str_response.encode()

        if(len(bytes_resp) > OAUTH2_MAX_CODE_RESPONSE_LENGTH):
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(414, "Request-URI Too Long")

        enc_response = oauth2_public_key_handler.encrypt(bytes_resp, 32)

        b64_enc_response_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(enc_response[0])
        b64_enc_response = b64_enc_response_bytes.decode()

        url = redirect_uri
        session_state = str(user.get("session_id", str(uuid.uuid4())))

        params = {response_type: b64_enc_response, "session_state": session_state}
        if state:
            params["state"] = state

        parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
        query = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(parts[4]))
        query.update(params)
        parts[4] = urlencode(query)

        redirect_url = urlparse.urlunparse(parts)

        self.redirect(redirect_url)

    @gen.coroutine
    def _do_token(self, requesting_user, params):
        code = params.get("code", None)
        grant_type = params.get("grant_type", None)
        redirect_uri = params.get("redirect_uri", None)
        resource = params.get("resource", None)
        state = params.get("state", None)
        client_id = params.get("client_id", None)
        client_secret = params.get("client_secret", None)
        refresh_token = params.get("refresh_token", None)
        tid = params.get("tenant_id", None)
        token_type = "bearer"

        # if grant_type == code then code must not be empty
        # if grant_type == refresh_token then refresh_token must not be empty
        if grant_type == "code":
            if not code:
                raise OAuth2RequestException("Code must not be empty when grant_type is code")
        elif grant_type == "refresh_token":
            if not refresh_token:
                raise OAuth2RequestException("Code must not be empty when grant_type is refresh_token")
        else:
            raise OAuth2RequestException("Value of grant_type must be either code or refresh_token")

        request_host = params.get("request_host")
        oauth2_token_issuer = self.settings.get("oauth2_token_issuer", request_host)
        oauth2_token_expiry_seconds = self.settings.get("oauth2_token_expiry_seconds")
        exp = datetime.timedelta(seconds=oauth2_token_expiry_seconds)

        enc_code = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(code.encode())
        oauth2_private_key_handler = self.settings.get("oauth2_private_key_handler")
        code_json_bytes = oauth2_private_key_handler.decrypt(enc_code)
        code_json = code_json_bytes.decode()
        code_dict = json.loads(code_json)

        user_id = code_dict.get("user_id")
        code_iat = code_dict.get("iat")

        if not user_id or not code_iat:
            raise OAuth2RequestException("Invalid code")

        user = yield self.load_user(user_id)
        if not user:
            raise OAuth2RequestException("Invalid code")

        #TODO: allow use of secret - otherwise its not secure

        #Make sure the code was not used earlier - otherwise its not secure
        code_status_id = code_dict.get("code_status_id")
        if not code_status_id:
            raise OAuth2RequestException("Invalid code")

        code_status = yield self.load_code_status(code_status_id)
        if not code_status:
            raise OAuth2RequestException("Invalid code. Possibly server error.")

        if code_status.get("used_at"):
            code_status["duplicate_attempt"] = True
            yield self.update_code_status(code_status)
            raise OAuth2RequestException("Code already used")

        code_status["used_at"] = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
        saved = yield self.update_code_status(code_status)
        if not saved:
            logging.error("Could not save code status Id={}".format(code_status_id))

        resource = code_dict.get("resource")
        oauth2_private_key_pem = self.get_private_key_pem()

        response = get_token(aud=client_id,
                                     exp=exp,
                                     family_name=user.get("family_name"),
                                     given_name=user.get("given_name"),
                                     iat=str(int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())),
                                     iss=oauth2_token_issuer,
                                     nbf=str(int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())),
                                     oid=str(user.get("_id")),
                                     sub=str(user.get("_id")),
                                     tid=tid,
                                     unique_name=user.get("username"),
                                     upn=user.get("username"),
                                     service_private_pem=oauth2_private_key_pem)
        url = redirect_uri
        session_state = user.get("session_id", str(uuid.uuid4()))
        response_type = "access_token"
        params = {response_type: response, "session_state": session_state, "token_type": token_type, "resource": resource}

        if state:
            params["state"] = state

        parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
        query = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(parts[4]))
        query.update(params)
        parts[4] = urlencode(query)

        redirect_url = urlparse.urlunparse(parts)

        self.redirect(redirect_url)

    def _collect_auth_request_parameters(self, tenant_id, function):
        params = {k: self.get_argument(k) for k in self.request.arguments}
        params["request_protocol"] = self.request.protocol
        params["request_host"] = self.request.host
        params["request_uri"] = self.request.uri
        params["tenant_id"] = tenant_id
        params["function"] = function

        return params

    @gen.coroutine
    def insert_auth_request(self, params):
        obj_serv = self.settings['object_service']
        promise = obj_serv.insert(SYSTEM_USER, OAUTH2_REQUESTS_OBJECT_NAME, params)
        req_id = yield promise
        return req_id

    @gen.coroutine
    def load_auth_request(self, req_id):
        obj_serv = self.settings['object_service']
        cursor = obj_serv.load(SYSTEM_USER, OAUTH2_REQUESTS_OBJECT_NAME, req_id, [])
        request = yield cursor
        return request

    @gen.coroutine
    def insert_code_status(self, response):
        obj_serv = self.settings['object_service']
        promise = obj_serv.insert(SYSTEM_USER, OAUTH2_CODE_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME, response)
        code_status_id = yield promise
        return code_status_id

    @gen.coroutine
    def update_code_status(self, code_status):
        obj_serv = self.settings['object_service']
        promise = obj_serv.save(SYSTEM_USER, OAUTH2_CODE_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME, code_status)
        code_status_id = yield promise
        return code_status_id

    @gen.coroutine
    def load_code_status(self, code_status_id):
        obj_serv = self.settings['object_service']
        promise = obj_serv.load(SYSTEM_USER, OAUTH2_CODE_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME, code_status_id, [])
        code_status = yield promise
        return code_status

    @gen.coroutine
    def load_user(self, user_id):
        obj_serv = self.settings['object_service']
        cursor = obj_serv.load(SYSTEM_USER, COSMOS_USERS_OBJECT_NAME, user_id, [])
        user = yield cursor
        return user

    def get_private_key_pem(self):
        return self.settings.get("oauth2_private_key_pem")
```

#### Token generation and validation code

```
def get_token(**kwargs):
    service_private_pem = kwargs.get("service_private_pem")
    if not service_private_pem:
        raise ValueError("service_private_pem is not defined")

    aud = kwargs.get("aud", None)
    exp = kwargs.get("exp", None)
    family_name = kwargs.get("family_name", None)
    given_name = kwargs.get("given_name", None)

    token_payload = {
        "aud": aud,
        "exp": exp,
        "family_name": family_name,
        "given_name": given_name,
        "ver": "1.0"
    }

    iss = kwargs.get("iss", None)
    if iss:
        token_payload["iss"] = iss

    nbf = kwargs.get("nbf", None)
    if nbf:
        token_payload["nbf"] = nbf

    oid = kwargs.get("oid", None)
    if oid:
        token_payload["oid"] = oid

    sub = kwargs.get("sub", None)
    if sub:
        token_payload["sub"] = sub

    tid = kwargs.get("tid", None)
    if tid:
        token_payload["tid"] = tid

    unique_name = kwargs.get("unique_name", None)
    if unique_name:
        token_payload["unique_name"] = unique_name

    upn = kwargs.get("upn", None)
    if upn:
        token_payload["upn"] = upn

    priv_key = RSA.importKey(service_private_pem)
    token = jwt.generate_jwt(token_payload, priv_key, 'RS256', exp)

    return token


def verify_token(token, public_key_pem, alg_list):
    try:
        header, claims = jwt.verify_jwt(token, public_key_pem, alg_list)
        return header, claims
    except Exception as ex:
        raise ValidationError(ex)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! "Draft" is OK, as long can claim that it "works".

Comment: Its a piece of code that deals with security - so very hard to tell people it is stable for production without deep tests and some evidence in production that it works.  Its new code, other than that it I can say it works.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second part first:

- In `verify_token` the return values are assigned - only to be
  immediately returned.  I get that it might be nice in a debugger(?)
  but there's really no reason for this - just return the values.  I'd
  possibly create a function that wraps other functions in such an
  exception handler, but that's probably overkill here.
- `dict.get` already defaults to returning `None` - I don't see a
  particular reason why you'd specify that everywhere.  Defaults are
  really useful to remove that clutter from your code.
- I'd also inline a lot of those variables to make the methods shorter
  (i.e. `aud`, `exp` and so on), or create a similar loop as described
  in the next point.
- The repeated pattern with `x = kwargs.get("x"); if x: ...["x"] = x`
  should also be refactored to remove repetition, e.g. by using a loop
  instead:

  ```py
  for name in ["iss", "nbf", "oid", "sub", "tid", "unique_name", "upn"]:
      x = kwargs.get(name)
      if x:
          token_payload[name] = x
  ```
- I'd also reorder code fragments that belong together.  At the moment
  the reader is jumping from `service_private_pem` to the initialisation
  of `token_payload` to only go back to the first variable in the second
  to last line, while `token_payload` is used in the last line.  I'd
  move the `RSA.importKey` after the first block, then handle the
  `token_payload` and all associated things after, that way the order of
  operation is clearly distinguished.

That leaves the following (could probably still be improved with more
factoring of code, but hey, looks compact enough to me):

```py
def get_token(**kwargs):
    service_private_pem = kwargs.get("service_private_pem")
    if not service_private_pem:
        raise ValueError("service_private_pem is not defined")
    priv_key = RSA.importKey(service_private_pem)

    token_payload = {"ver": "1.0"}

    for name in ["aud", "exp", "family_name", "given_name"]:
        token_payload[name] = kwargs.get(name)

    for name in ["iss", "nbf", "oid", "sub", "tid", "unique_name", "upn"]:
        x = kwargs.get(name)
        if x:
            token_payload[name] = x

    return jwt.generate_jwt(token_payload, priv_key, 'RS256', exp)
```

---

Now for the first part.  Well that's a lot of code.  Okay, so small
stuff:

- Empty returns with no other afterwards don't do anything, so I'd leave
  them out.
- `logging` already supports arguments using `%s` and friends - the
  calls can thus be written like `logging.debug("... %s", req_id)` etc.
- the six coroutine methods look awfully similar.  I'm not too familiar
  with generators or the framework, so this could be wrong:

  ```py
  def _request_helper(self, *args):
      obj_serv = self.settings["object_service"]
      promise = obj_serv.insert(SYSTEM_USER, OAUTH2_REQUESTS_OBJECT_NAME, *args)
      req_id = yield promise
      return req_id
  ```

  This helper would then reused from the individual methods (though at
  that point you could as well use that method directly?):

  ```py
  @gen.coroutine
  def insert_auth_request(self, params):
      return self._request_helper(params)
  ```
- In `_collect_auth_request_parameters` the update of the dictionary
  could be a bit more compact:

  ```py
  def _collect_auth_request_parameters(self, tenant_id, function):
      params = {k: self.get_argument(k) for k in self.request.arguments}
      params.update({
          "request_protocol": self.request.protocol,
          "request_host": self.request.host,
          "request_uri": self.request.uri,
          "tenant_id": tenant_id,
          "function": function
      })
      return params
  ```
- Having these giant `try/except` blocks is just increasing the
  indentation.  I'd suggest that the inner part is either compacted so
  much as to fit into one screen, or moved into its own method.
- Similarly having the `return` cases early can remove the indentation
  from the `else` branch, which makes the flow also a bit more clear.
  Initialising variables to `None` is also mostly not that useful.
- `_do_authorize` is just convoluted and can be cleaned up a lot by
  removing all the code moving values around between the dictionaries.
  And again, sprinkling assignments out over the method like this makes
  for a great treasure hunt, but doesn't help understanding the code too
  much.  Reassigning `params` also tripped me up during rewriting.
- `_do_token` is similarly just too much - perhaps no wonder considering
  it looks mostly like copy & paste from the method before.  IMO that's
  the biggest mistake as it requires a lot of attention when trying to
  deduplicate it again.  It's better to spend the effort creating a
  "DRY" implementation from the start.
- The exceptions are mostly similar and can be moved into methods.

Actually I got confused when trying to clean up `_do_authorize` and
`_do_token`, so I'll give up on that for now.  I can imagine that other
readers might have a similar problem.  I strongly suggest to
aggressively factor out common functions and creating more methods,
helper functions, whatever to help keep the line count and number of
variables to read down.